# Is the yellow claptrap in arid badlands an easter egg or something else?

Tags: borderlands

I recently began playthrough 2 so I'm located in arid badlands. I killed Bone Head and while wandering back I saw this yellow claptrap.

[image: Zoomed out]
[image: Zoomed in]

So is this one just an easter egg or something else?

Comment: Wow, never saw that one...not aware of him doing anything

Comment: What a sneaky little fella. I was terrified the first time I saw the red one.

Comment: Good eye, I've played Borderlands quite a bit and never noticed him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to get up there, but it's a tricky place to get to:

As far as I know, it's just an easter egg - there's nothing much that this Claptrap does.  Someone on the YouTube video said that you get XP for saying there a while; I never noticed this on my playthrough.  He is decorated with Gearbox colors, for what that's worth :)